# Containers cannot reach each others in docker-compose

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, dns, systemd

I'm using this docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.7"

networks:
  test_net:
    internal: true

services:
  A:
    image: nginx:1.17
    networks:
      - test_net

  B:
    image: node:14-alpine
    command: wget A
    networks:
      - test_net
```

output:

```
Creating network "test_test_net" with the default driver
Creating test_B_1 ... done
Creating test_A_1 ... done
Attaching to test_A_1, test_B_1
B_1  | Connecting to A (172.24.0.2:80)
B_1  | wget: can't connect to remote host (172.24.0.2): Host is unreachable
test_B_1 exited with code 1
```

Container B can resolve the name of container A but cannot reach it.

Edit: I've been looking around and it seems it could be systemd-networkd problem with docker0 interface.

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday I had a similar problem, when I put something like this:

```
network: 
 it-network:
   driver: bridge
```

The services can´t reach each other, i think is because, delegates the creation of the network to docker-compose file.

But when i create the network first:

```
docker network create --driver bridge it-network
```

And then use it in the docker-compose.yml file

```
services: 
 service1: 
  networks:
   - it-networks
.....
networks:
 default: 
  external: 
    name: it-network
```

Works fine.

Usefull commands i use:

```
docker network inspect it-network
```

Other solution i've found is use extend directive, with this you can share configurations between services and different docker-compose files.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/

but i don't test it yet.

The services I use in the docker-compose file

- postgres(from docker hub)
- Jira Software (precompiled image from Dockerfile)

My docker compose file is this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgresql-jira:
    image: postgres:9.5-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgresqldata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - 'POSTGRES_USER=devops'
      # CHANGE THE PASSWORD!
      - 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxx'
      - 'POSTGRES_DB=jiradb'
      - 'POSTGRES_ENCODING=UNICODE'
      - 'POSTGRES_COLLATE=C'
      - 'POSTGRES_COLLATE_TYPE=C'
    logging:
      # limit logs retained on host to 25MB
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "500k"
        max-file: "50"
  jira-software:
    depends_on:
      - postgresql-jira
    image: XXX/jira-server:8.8.1
    volumes:
      - jiradata:/var/atlassian/jira
    ports:
      - '80:8080'
    environment:
      - 'JIRA_DATABASE_URL=postgresql://devops@postgresql/jiradb'
      - 'JIRA_DB_PASSWORD=xxx'
      - 'SETENV_JVM_MINIMUM_MEMORY=2048m'
      - 'SETENV_JVM_MAXIMUM_MEMORY=4096m'
      - 'JIRA_PROXY_NAME='
      - 'JIRA_PROXY_PORT='
      - 'JIRA_PROXY_SCHEME='
    links: 
      - "postgresql-jira:postgresql-jira-db"
    logging:
      # limit logs retained on host to 25MB
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "500k"
        max-file: "50"

volumes:
  jiradata:
    external: false
  postgresqldata:
    external: false

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: it-network
```

Comment: I've tried my docker-compose.yml on https://labs.play-with-docker.com/ as a clean environment, and it seems to work as expected, must be something with my system network configuration

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to configure your network in the following way?
Pay attention you'll use the BRIDGE mode here.

```
networks:
  test_net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 177.10.10.0/24
```

I configured mine and you can check it at https://github.com/guerrato/docker_config

PS: There might be services that need to have their Dockerfile updated, but you can trust on docker-compose.yml

Comment: I tried this but it's not working anyway, and second off, this is a hack, docker should be able to use an internal network to communicate with other containers

Answer (score -2):

Try to add hostname or link for each instance

```
services:
  A:
  image: nginx:1.17
  hostname: A
  networks:
    - test_net

B:
  image: node:14-alpine
  hostname: B
  command: wget A
  networks:
    - test_net
```